# Get co-ordinates of image in pdf

Tags: image, pdf, itext

In my project, I want to find co-ordinates of image in pdf. I tried searching itext and pdfbox, but I was not succesful. Using these co-ordinates and extracted image, I want to verify whether the extracted image is same as image present in database, and co-ordinates of image are same as present in database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say that you've tried with iText, I assume that you've used the [ExtractImages](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=284) example as the starting point for your code. This example uses the helper class [MyImageRenderListener](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=283), which implements the `RenderListener` interface.

In that helper class the `renderImage()` method is implemented like this:

```
public void renderImage(ImageRenderInfo renderInfo) {
    try {
        String filename;
        FileOutputStream os;
        PdfImageObject image = renderInfo.getImage();
        if (image == null) return;
        filename = String.format(path, renderInfo.getRef().getNumber(), image.getFileType());
        os = new FileOutputStream(filename);
        os.write(image.getImageAsBytes());
        os.flush();
        os.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

It uses the `ImageRenderInfo` object to obtain a `PdfImageObject` instance and it creates an image file using that object.

If you inspect the [`ImageRenderInfo`](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/parser/ImageRenderInfo.html) class, you'll discover that you can also ask for other info about the image. What you need, is the [`getImageCTM()`](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/parser/ImageRenderInfo.html#getImageCTM%28%29) method. This method returns a [`Matrix`](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/parser/Matrix.html) object. This matrix can be interpreted using ordinary high-school algebra. The values `I31` and `I32` give you the X and Y position. In most cases `I11` and `I22` will give you the width and the height (unless the image is rotated).

If the image is rotated, you'll have to consult your high-school schoolbooks, more specifically the ones discussing analytic geometry.