# Find Image Co-ordiantes in PDF using iTextSharp/Tesseract c#

Tags: c#, image, itext, coordinates, tesseract

I'm new to PDF related developments. Now, I need to get the co-ordinates of Image files embed in PDF either Using iTextSharp or Tesseract. Please guide me or please share the coding snippets.

Thanks in advance!

`

```
class Program
    {
        public static void GetImage(string pPath)
        {
            try
            {
                if (!File.Exists(pPath)){ Console.WriteLine("Invalid Path!"); return;}
                PdfReader pRdr = new PdfReader(pPath);
                PdfReaderContentParser parser = new PdfReaderContentParser(pRdr);
                ImageRenderListener listener = new ImageRenderListener("testpdf");

                for (int i = 1; i <= pRdr.NumberOfPages; i++)
                {
                    parser.ProcessContent(i, listener); 
                }
            }
            catch (Exception error)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(error.Message);
            }
        }



        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Program.GetImage(@"D:\J\FM - Copy.pdf");
        }
    }`
```

`

```
class ImageRenderListener:IRenderListener
    {
        public String name;
        int counter = 100000;

        public ImageRenderListener(String name)
        {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public void BeginTextBlock() { }
        public void RenderText(TextRenderInfo renderInfo) { }
        public void EndTextBlock() { }

        public void RenderImage(ImageRenderInfo renderInfo)
        {
            try
            {
                PdfImageObject image = renderInfo.GetImage();
                if (image == null) return;
                int number = renderInfo.GetRef() != null ? renderInfo.GetRef().Number : counter++;
                String filename = String.Format("%s-%s.%s", name, number, image.GetFileType());

                FileStream os = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
                os.Write(image.GetImageAsBytes(), 0, 0);
                os.Flush();
                os.Close();

                PdfDictionary imageDictionary = image.GetDictionary();
                PRStream maskStream = (PRStream)imageDictionary.GetAsStream(PdfName.SMASK);
                if (maskStream != null)
                {
                    PdfImageObject maskImage = new PdfImageObject(maskStream);
                    filename = String.Format("%s-%s-mask.%s", name, number, maskImage.GetFileType());
                    os = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
                    os.Write(maskImage.GetImageAsBytes(), 0, 0);
                    os.Flush();
                    os.Close();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
        }
    }`
```

Comment: Have you done any research already? Do you have any code that you've had a shot at but just doesn't quite seem to work?

Comment: Hi, Yonik.. I just added my code here.

Comment: Look at the other getters of the `ImageRenderInfo renderInfo`, the matrix among them informs you about position, scaling, rotation, etc. of the image on the page.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get co-ordinates of image in pdf](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24055187/get-co-ordinates-of-image-in-pdf)

Comment: Thanks for your replies guys.. @Bruno Lowagie: As given in below  link [Get co-ordinates of image in pdf](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24055187/get-co-ordinates-of-image-in-pdf) this will work for Raster Images in PDF. But in my sample, some vector images are also there. Is there any way to get co-ordinates of vector images [RasterVsVector](http://www.graffixinc.com/docs/rastervector.pdf)

Comment: No, the latest iText version allows you to retrieve operators such as `m` (move to) and `l` (line to) and there operands (such as the coordinates to move to or to line to). But you have to interpret those operators. Those operators are PDF's way of drawing vector images. I'm not sure in which vector format you want to receive "raster images". There is no such thing as WMF or SVG in PDF.